# Extension [/opt/apache-druid-0.20.1/dist/druid/extensions/druid-orc-extensions] specified in "druid.extensions.loadList" didn't exist?

Tags: kubernetes, druid

I am trying to deploy apache/druid:0.20.1 in Kube. I am getting error:

```
Extension [/opt/apache-druid-0.20.1/dist/druid/extensions/druid-orc-extensions] specified in "druid.extensions.loadList" didn't exist!?
```

I have taken off druid-orc-extensions from extensions list in my common properties but still getting the same for the next one druid-s3-extensions and so on. I somewhere on Google found that repositoryList solved the issue. I did try:

```
druid.extensions.repositoryList=[ "druid-hdfs-storage", "druid-kafka-indexing-service", "druid-datasketches","druid-s3-extensions", "druid-kafka-indexing-service", "postgresql-metadata-storage", "druid-parquet-extensions", "druid-datasketches", "druid-basic-security"]
```

Now, I did not get error, but its not able to connect too Postgres Metadata and giving error:

```
2021-04-01T14:14:06,926 ERROR [main] org.apache.druid.cli.CliCoordinator - Error when starting up. Failing.
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:
1) Unknown provider[postgresql] of Key[type=org.apache.druid.metadata.MetadataStorageProvider, annotation=[none]], known options[[derby]]
 at org.apache.druid.guice.PolyBind.createChoiceWithDefault(PolyBind.java:109) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> org.apache.druid.metadata.storage.derby.DerbyMetadataStorageDruidModule)
 while locating org.apache.druid.metadata.MetadataStorageProvider
 while locating org.apache.druid.metadata.MetadataStorage
```

and when I dont give extension.loadList in common.runtime.properties, it is trying to load all the extensions and then giving error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:
1) No implementation for org.apache.druid.query.QuerySegmentWalker was bound.
  while locating com.google.inject.Provider<org.apache.druid.query.QuerySegmentWalker>
    for the 1st parameter of org.apache.druid.query.movingaverage.MovingAverageQueryToolChest.<init>(MovingAverageQueryToolChest.java:61)
  at org.apache.druid.query.movingaverage.MovingAverageQueryModule.configure(MovingAverageQueryModule.java:48) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> org.apache.druid.query.movingaverage.MovingAverageQueryModule)
2) No implementation for org.apache.druid.client.TimelineServerView was bound.
  while locating org.apache.druid.client.TimelineServerView
    for the 1st parameter of org.apache.druid.query.materializedview.DataSourceOptimizer.<init>(DataSourceOptimizer.java:62)
  at org.apache.druid.query.materializedview.MaterializedViewSelectionDruidModule.configure(MaterializedViewSelectionDruidModule.java:55) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> org.apache.druid.query.materializedview.MaterializedViewSelectionDruidModule)
3) No implementation for org.apache.druid.query.QueryToolChestWarehouse was bound.
  while locating org.apache.druid.query.QueryToolChestWarehouse
    for the 1st parameter of org.apache.druid.query.materializedview.MaterializedViewQueryQueryToolChest.<init>(MaterializedViewQueryQueryToolChest.java:48)
  at org.apache.druid.query.materializedview.MaterializedViewSelectionDruidModule.configure(MaterializedViewSelectionDruidModule.java:52) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> org.apache.druid.query.materializedview.MaterializedViewSelectionDruidModule)
4) No implementation for org.apache.druid.server.log.RequestLogger was bound.
  while locating org.apache.druid.server.log.RequestLogger
    for the 2nd parameter of org.apache.druid.query.movingaverage.MovingAverageQueryToolChest.<init>(MovingAverageQueryToolChest.java:61)
  at org.apache.druid.query.movingaverage.MovingAverageQueryModule.configure(MovingAverageQueryModule.java:48) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> org.apache.druid.query.movingaverage.MovingAverageQueryModule)
5) A binding to com.google.common.base.Supplier<org.apache.druid.server.audit.SQLAuditManagerConfig> was already configured at org.apache.druid.guice.JsonConfigProvider.bind(JsonConfigProvider.java:151) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> org.apache.druid.metadata.storage.mysql.MySQLMetadataStorageModule).
  at org.apache.druid.guice.JsonConfigProvider.bind(JsonConfigProvider.java:151) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> org.apache.druid.metadata.storage.postgresql.PostgreSQLMetadataStorageModule)
6) A binding to com.google.common.base.Supplier<org.apache.druid.server.audit.SQLAuditManagerConfig> was already configured at org.apache.druid.guice.JsonConfigProvider.bind(JsonConfigProvider.java:151) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> org.apache.druid.metadata.storage.mysql.MySQLMetadataStorageModule).
  at org.apache.druid.guice.JsonConfigProvider.bind(JsonConfigProvider.java:151) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> org.apache.druid.metadata.storage.sqlserver.SQLServerMetadataStorageModule)
7) A binding to org.apache.druid.server.audit.SQLAuditManagerConfig was already configured at org.apache.druid.guice.JsonConfigProvider.bind(JsonConfigProvider.java:152) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> org.apache.druid.metadata.storage.mysql.MySQLMetadataStorageModule).
  at org.apache.druid.guice.JsonConfigProvider.bind(JsonConfigProvider.java:152) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> org.apache.druid.metadata.storage.postgresql.PostgreSQLMetadataStorageModule)
8) A binding to org.apache.druid.server.audit.SQLAuditManagerConfig was already configured at org.apache.druid.guice.JsonConfigProvider.bind(JsonConfigProvider.java:152) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> org.apache.druid.metadata.storage.mysql.MySQLMetadataStorageModule).
  at org.apache.druid.guice.JsonConfigProvider.bind(JsonConfigProvider.java:152) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> org.apache.druid.metadata.storage.sqlserver.SQLServerMetadataStorageModule)
```

Comment: How does your `druid.extensions.loadList` from `runtime.properties` look like?

Answer (score 0):

Check this `druid_extensions_loadList`. It can be in the environment file, or you can locate it in which file by using this command in the terminal:

```
grep -r "druid_extensions_loadList" path/to/your/folder
```

Then, you can modify this list (using `nano` or `gedit` cmd) and remove druid-orc-extensions from the `druid_extensions_loadList`.
If this extension is necessary, make sure that it is installed.